# Back button is failing in Spring MVC 3

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have gone through many forums to resolve the solution of Back button in MVC 3. When I click on back button, previous page is not displayed but when refreshed it is. I have tried with:

```
response.setHeader( "Expires", "0" );
// set standard HTTP/1.1 no-cache headers (post-check and pre-check for IE)
response.setHeader( "Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0, max-age=0, proxy-revalidate, no-transform, private");
// set standard HTTP/1.0 no-cache header
response.setHeader( "Pragma", "no-cache" );
```

but still no clue. Can you tell me how I can request the browser to refresh or get data from server?